# Using multi-thread ,Build a simple HTTP server in C

Tags: multithreading, http, web, server

As a school project , i was asked to build a simple HTTP server which can handle and process multiple and simultaneous requests , and to proof that this server will deliver my home page to the internet browser. (Using RFC 1945/HTTP 1.0)

I took a part of my project so you know how it goes 
 - the server listens to a fixed port. When it receives a TCP connection request, it sets up a TCP connection through another port and services the request in a separate thread. To simplify this programming task, we will develop the code in two stages. In the first stage, you will write a multi-threaded server that simply displays the contents of the HTTP request message that it receives. After this program is running properly, you will add the code required to generate an appropriate response.

Any ideas or samples?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample of http server with thread pool which I wrote a year ago:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define KB 1024
/*function declerations*/

void send_content(int fd, int connfd,int isDir,char* path);
void enqueue(int data);
void* dequeue(void* ptr);
void send_to_client(int connfd, char* line);

/*global vars*/
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t emp;
int sock =0;
int max_threads =0;
int global_count=0;
int finished =1;
int length=0;

/*Queue*/
struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *ptr;
}*head,*tail;
struct sigaction ready, last;



int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int threads;
    int requests; 
    int port;
    int i; 
    int s; 
    int len_of_packet=1; 
    int fd;
    int port1; 
    int file;   
    char content[16000];
    char  *fileContent ;
    int thrd ;
    int rc;
    char method[KB];
    char path[KB];
    int s_len=0; 
    int r_len=0;
    int fileLen; 
    int parsing;
    unsigned int addr_size;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
    struct stat st;
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir;
    static fd_set readsocks, socks;
    char buf[KB] ;
    char Uniform_Resource_Identifier[KB];
    int servfd; 
    int socket_of_accept; 

    off_t chunk=0;
    size_t readData;
    int sent;

    assert (argc ==3 || argc ==4);


    threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (threads == LONG_MAX || threads == LONG_MIN))
            || (errno != 0 && threads == 0)) {
        perror("Error: strtol has been failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    max_threads = threads;
    requests = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (requests == LONG_MAX || requests == LONG_MIN))
            || (errno != 0 && requests == 0)) {
        perror("Error: strtol has been failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    port = 80; 

    if (argc == 4){
        port = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
        if ((errno == ERANGE && (port == LONG_MAX || port == LONG_MIN))
                || (errno != 0 && port == 0)) {
            perror("Error: strtol has been failed\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    pthread_t threadsArr[threads];


    if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL)!=0){
        printf("Error: failed to init mutex\n");
        return 1;   
    }

    pthread_cond_init( &emp, NULL);


    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;

    /*create threads*/
    for (thrd=0; thrd<threads;thrd++){
        rc = pthread_create(&threadsArr[thrd], NULL,  dequeue, (void*) &thrd);
        if (rc){
            printf("Error: failed to create thread\n");
            return 1;   
        }
    }

    /* create socket */
    servfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sock = servfd;
    if (servfd == -1) {
        printf("Error creating socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* init prepernces */
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* bind */
    setsockopt(servfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &len_of_packet,sizeof(int));
    if (bind(servfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) {
        printf("Error: Bind has been failed\n");
        perror ("Bind: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*listen */
    if (listen(servfd, requests) == -1) {
        printf("Error: Listen has been failed\n");
        perror ("Listen: ");
        exit(1); 
    }

    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(servfd, &socks);

    int startLen = strlen("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
            "<doctype !html><html><head><title></title>"
            "<style>body"
            "h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
            "}</style></head>"
            "<body><h1>Service Unavailable (HTTP 503)</h1></body></html>\r\n");
    int endLen = strlen("</h1></body></html>\r\n");


    while(1){

        sigfillset(&ready.sa_mask);
        ready.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
        ready.sa_flags = 0;

        if (sigaction(SIGINT, &ready,&last) || sigaction(SIGINT,&last,NULL)){
            finished=0;
            for(i=0; i<threads; i++){
                rc = pthread_join(threadsArr[i], NULL);
                if(rc != 0){
                    printf("Error: join has been failed\n");
                    perror("Join: ");
                    return 1;   
                }
            }
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
            close(sock);
        }


        addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        socket_of_accept = accept(servfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_size);
        if (socket_of_accept == -1) {
            printf("Error: Accept has been failed\n");
            perror ("Accept: ");
            exit(1);
        }


        enqueue(socket_of_accept);
        if (length <= requests){

            /*recieve message*/
            r_len = recv(socket_of_accept, buf, KB,0);
            if (r_len == -1){
                printf("Error: recieve has been  %d\n", socket_of_accept);
                close(socket_of_accept);
                exit(1);
            }

            sscanf(buf,"%s %s", method, Uniform_Resource_Identifier);
            sscanf(Uniform_Resource_Identifier,"%s", path);
            printf("method = %s, path = %s\n", method, path);

            /*GET OR POST*/
            if(strcmp(method, "GET")!= 0 && strcmp(method, "POST") != 0){
                char response[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
                        "<doctype !html><html><head><title></title>"
                        "<style>body"
                        "h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
                        "}</style></head>"
                        "<body><h1>Service Unavailable (HTTP 503)</h1></body></html>\r\n";
                s_len = send(socket_of_accept, response, strlen(response), 0);
                if (s_len == -1){
                    printf("Error: failed to send message %s to client %d\n", response, socket_of_accept);
                    close(socket_of_accept);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            if (stat(path, &st) == -1){ /*file not found*/
                char response[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
                        "<doctype !html><html><head><title></title>"
                        "<style>body"
                        "h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
                        "}</style></head>"
                        "<body><h1>Not Found  (HTTP 404)</h1></body></html>\r\n";
                s_len = send(socket_of_accept, response, strlen(response), 0);
                if (s_len == -1){
                    printf("Error: failed to send message %s to client %d\n", response, socket_of_accept);
                    close(socket_of_accept);
                    exit(1);
                }
                close(socket_of_accept);
            }else {

                if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)){/*directory*/

                    if((dir = opendir (path)) != NULL){


                        send_content(fd, socket_of_accept,1,path);

                        close(socket_of_accept);

                    }else{
                        printf("Error: failed to open directory: %s\n", path);
                    }


                }else if(S_ISREG(st.st_mode) && st.st_size != 0){/*regular file*/


                    fd=open(path,O_RDONLY);
                    send_content(fd, socket_of_accept,0,path);

                    close(file);
                    close(socket_of_accept);


                }

                else{/*empty file*/
                    char response[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
                            "<doctype !html><html><head><title></title>"
                            "<style>body"
                            "h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
                            "}</style></head>"
                            "<body><h1> </h1></body></html>\r\n";
                    s_len = send(socket_of_accept, response, strlen(response), 0);
                    if (s_len == -1){
                        printf("Error: failed to send message %s to client %d\n", response, socket_of_accept);
                        close(socket_of_accept);
                        exit(1);

                    }
                }
            }

        }else{/*full queue*/
            /*send (HTTP 503)*/

            char response[3000] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
                    "<doctype !html><html><head><title></title>"
                    "<style>body"
                    "h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
                    "}</style></head>"
                    "<body><h1>Service Unavailable  (HTTP 503)</h1></body></html>\r\n";
            s_len = send(socket_of_accept, response, strlen(response), 0);
            if (s_len == -1){
                printf("Error: unable to send a message %s to: %d\n", response, socket_of_accept);
                close(socket_of_accept);
                exit(1);

            }
            close(socket_of_accept);
        }


    }

    return 0;
}






void send_content(int fd, int connfd,int isDir,char* path){
    char line[KB];
    memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

    send_to_client(connfd, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n");

    int return_value;
    if(!isDir){
        while ((return_value=read(fd, line, KB)) > 0) {
            send_to_client(connfd, line);
            memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
        }
        if (return_value < 0){
            perror("Error read");
            send_to_client(connfd, "Error Resorces\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        DIR           *d;
        struct dirent *dir;
        d = opendir(path);
        if (d)
        {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
            {
                strcpy(line,dir->d_name);
                strcat(line,"\n");
                send_to_client(connfd,line);
                memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
            }

            closedir(d);
        }
    }
}


/*enqueue*/
void enqueue(int data)
{
    int rc;
    struct node* temp;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Error: couldn't allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->ptr = NULL;
    temp->info = data;

    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&lock) !=0){
        printf("Error: failed to lock\n");
        exit(1);
    } 



    if (length == 0) /*empty queue*/
    {
        head = temp;

    }else 
    {
        tail->ptr = temp; 
    }

    tail = temp;
    length++;
    rc = pthread_cond_broadcast(&emp);
    assert(rc==0);
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)!=0){
        printf("Error: failed to unlock\n");
        pthread_exit(0);
    }


    return;
}





void send_to_client(int connfd, char* line){
    int nsent, totalsent;
    int notwritten = strlen(line);

    /* keep looping until nothing left to write*/
    totalsent = 0;
    while (notwritten > 0){
        /* notwritten = how much we have left to write
            totalsent  = how much we've written so far
            nsent = how much we've written in last write() call */
        nsent = write(connfd, line + totalsent, notwritten);
        assert(nsent>=0); // check if error occured (client closed connection?)

        totalsent  += nsent;
        notwritten -= nsent;
    }
}







/*dequeue*/
void* dequeue(void* ptr)
{
    int rc;
    int i=0;
    int thread = *((int*)ptr);

    struct node* temp;

    while(finished){

        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&lock) !=0){
            printf("Error: lock has been failed\n");
            pthread_exit(0);
        }

        while (length == 0)
        {
            rc = pthread_cond_wait(&emp, &lock);
            assert(rc == 0);
        }

        int info = head->info;
        temp = head;
        head = head->ptr;
        free(temp);


        length--;
        rc = pthread_cond_broadcast(&emp);
        assert(rc==0);
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)!=0){
            printf("Error: unlock has been failed\n");
            pthread_exit(0);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```